# How to solve the problem that added widgets don't appear on screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a code to add a group, to add additional children within that group.

I checked that it was well added through the print(fields.length);.

But it doesn't even work on the screen even through It called through setState. Please help me get it on the screen.

I have to make it in the same class for list management!!

```
List<Widget> groups = [];

group() {
  List<Widget> fields = [];
  return Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: fields,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              fields.add(field(fields));
              print(fields.length);
            });
          },
          child: const Text('add'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

field(List<Widget> fields) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: groups,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              groups.add(group());
            });
          },
          child: const Text('add'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you are doing wrong. First, remember it is always a bad idea to return widgets in functions. Always use a separate stateless/stateful widget to manage that widget's state. I have rewrote you code in the right way and I would suggest you to follow this for your future implementation.

I have created separate files/classes for groups and fields widgets.

Field is a stateless class as you will never update the state of this widget.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Field extends StatelessWidget {
  const Field({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
      ),
      width: 100,
      height: 50,
    );
  }
}
```

Group will be a stateful class as this will hold the list of field widgets.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testcounter/field.dart';

class Groups extends StatefulWidget {
  const Groups({super.key});

  @override
  State<Groups> createState() => _GroupsState();
}

class _GroupsState extends State<Groups> {
  List<Widget> fields = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: fields,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                fields.add(const Field());
              });
            },
            child: const Text('Add Red'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Ultimately, you final homescreen or build function should look like this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.
  // This class is the configuration for the state.
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> groups = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: groups,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  groups.add(const Groups());
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Add Blue'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You need to have a clear understanding on how state reloads a widget. Also, statemanagement packages like GetX, Bloc, etc. can help you greatly to load only the widgets that will change.